# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Reference taken from here (My code exactly same as this repo)- https://github.com/DamianMielcarek/CRM/tree/master/src/main/java/crm

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ce77a01.customUserDetailsService(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.SecurityConfig.configureGlobal(SecurityConfig.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com..BenimcarsApplication.main(BenimcarsApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringDataUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
        return new SpringDataUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/user/delete/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/pdf-generator", "/search/**", "/customer/**", "/user/edit/**", "/user/list", "/contract/**").hasAnyRole( "ADMIN", "USER", "MANAGER", "OWNER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    Iterable<User> listAllUsers();
    User showUser(Long id);
    void saveUser(User user);
    void editUser(User user);
    void deleteUser(User user);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private SpringDataUserDetailsService springDataUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRoleRepository(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringDataUserDetailsService(SpringDataUserDetailsService springDataUserDetailsService) {
        this.springDataUserDetailsService = springDataUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> listAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAllByEnabled(1);
    }

    @Override
    public User showUser(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
        user.setRole(userRole);
        user.setEnabled(1);
        String password = user.getPassword();
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        userRepository.save(user);
        if (user.getId().equals(1L)) {
            userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
            user.setRole(userRole);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
        UserDetails userDetails = springDataUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void editUser(User user) {
        String password = user.getPassword();
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
        try {
            userRole = roleRepository.findById(user.getRole().getId()).orElse(null);;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
        } finally {
            user.setRole(userRole);
            user.setEnabled(1);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        user.setEnabled(0);
        user.setPassword(null);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

SpringDataUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class SpringDataUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        String role = user.getRole().getName();
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser();
        currentUser.setUser(user);
        currentUser.setAuthorities(grantedAuthorities);
        return currentUser;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `UserService` needs beans created by the `ScurityConfig` while your `SpringDataUserDetailsService` requires the `UserService` and your `SecurityConfig` requires the `SpringDataUserDetailsService`. Hence circulair dependencies. To make things worse the `SpringDatauserDetailsService` needs the `UserService` and vice-versa. I suggest go back to the design board and redesign this,

Comment: Note that calling `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` is redundant. Since `customUserDetailsService` and` passwordEncoder` are beans, Spring Security will pick them up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The project you're referring to uses Spring Boot 1.5.10. If you're trying to use Spring Boot 2.6.0 or higher, you'll need to either resolve the circular references as mentioned by others, or set `spring.main.allow-circular-references` to `true`.

See the [Spring Boot 2.6 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default) for more information.